# How is this static method called on a instance value wrong?

Tags: java

> How is this legal

```
System.out.println("".valueOf(1121997));
```

> And this is **illegal**

```
System.out.println(1.valueOf("1121997"));
```

Comment: String is object and 1 is int which is primitive type.

Comment: It'd work with another pair of parentheses.

Comment: Don't go changing the question when the edits make already existing answers invalid.

Comment: Rolled back edit invalidating answers.

Comment: By the way, you should never ever do this in real life, calling static methods on instances (particularly unrelated instances) is a Very Bad Idea™.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "" is a String. String Class has a valueOf method, so you can call it.

For your old question,

```
System.out.println( 1.valueOf("1121997"));
```

Here 1 is primitive integer value and not Integer Wrapper class. You can not call method on primitive data types.

For your updated Question,

```
System.out.println((Integer) 1.valueOf("1121997"));
```

Here you need to wrap **(Integer)1** with additional ().

```
System.out.println(((Integer) 1).valueOf("1121997"));
```

Also valueOf() is a static method. It is not a good practice to call it with instance. You should call it directly with class name like

```
Integer.valueOf("1121997");
```

Comment: `(Integer)1` is a valid cast.

Comment: can you please tell why additional () is required

Comment: @SanjayIdpuganti in its simplest form, it **AutoBoxes** the `1`, which 
is a primitive

Comment: @SanjayIdpuganti : If you don't add wrapper () , compiler will understand it as you are calling that method on primitive literal. Once you add wrapper () , Compiler will cast primitive int to Integer wrapper class and then call its Integer.valueOf() method. Hope i clarified your doubt. Happy Learning :)

Comment: @SanjayIdpuganti, study order of operations and precedence in Java to see why and where parentheses are needed.

Answer (score 5):

`""` is a string literal, and the java compiler makes sure that a `String` object will be automatically created for each string literal that you use in your program.  So, since `""` is an object, it has methods like `valueOf()`.

On the other hand, `1` is an `int` literal, so there is no object created for it; it is just a *primitive*.  Primitives do not have methods in java.

Comment: Worth noting, `valueOf` is a static method so you don't actually need an instance/object at all.

Comment: 1 is an **int** literal; not an Integer. There are no Integer literals.

Comment: There are no Integer literals, but there are integer literals.

Comment: @GhostCat I corrected it because you do admittedly have 10% of a point.  
 ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Actually, the official tutorials use the term `Integer Literals` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: @Shashwat nice find!  C-:=  But that's only because "Integer Literals" is a title.  Further down within the sentence they say "integer literals".

Comment: "Integer" or "integer" ? And keep in mind: tutorials are tutorials. When we start playing the "official documents say" game; the **only** viable resource would be the JLS; which I am too lazy to look up now.

Comment: [***THERE AREN'T "string literals" THERE ARE ONLY "String literals"***](https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder824/500x/57742824.jpg)

Comment: @MikeNakis pulled up the JLS, and see what I found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4). I guess we could just keep arguing over this :)

Comment: `String` refers to a Java type. "String" or "string" refer to the abstraction the type represents.

Answer (score 1):

`""` is a **reference to a String Object**, therefore has methods like `length`, `valueOf`, etc.

`1` is an `integer` **literal**. It is a *primitive* data type, therefore you can't call methods on it.

Comment: *"`1` is an `Integer` literal"* No, it's an `int` literal. There are no `Integer` literals.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  funnily enough, even the official tutorials use the term `Integer Literals` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: They may say "integer literal" (which is common practice), but I don't think you'll find any that says what you had originally, "`Integer` literal" -- code formatting is meaningful. :-)